# JTable doesn`t update on repaint() via PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I`m programming a user client for a mysql database which reads data from the database and displays it in a JTable. I`ve come that far, that the PropertyChangeEvent is sent and received with the right data. rowData and columnName have the new and updated data. If created a empty table to show at start of the programm. Although i have the right data and I call repaint() it does`t update the JTable.
I`ve searched the web and stackoverflow for quite some hours now and didn`t find a fitting answer to my problem.

Here is the code:

```
public class SuchenPanel extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener{

protected SuchenComboBoxControl comboControl = new SuchenComboBoxControl();
protected String[][] rowData = StringTools.makeRowData(comboControl.getCurrentRs()); 
protected String[] columnName = StringTools.makeColumnName(comboControl.getCurrentRs());
protected JTable tableView = new JTable(rowData,columnName);
protected JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tableView);


public SuchenPanel(){

    comboControl.addPropertyChangeListener(this);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel north = new JPanel();
    north.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,6,3));

    JComboBox<Object> tableBox= new JComboBox<Object>(TablesColoumns.TABLES);
    tableBox.setActionCommand(SuchenCommand.TABLE);
    tableBox.addActionListener(comboControl);
    north.add(new JLabel("In welcher Tabelle wollen Sie suchen?"));
    north.add(tableBox);
    add(north,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
}


@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
    String propertyName = e.getPropertyName();
    if(propertyName.equals(PropertyChangeCommands.tableUPDATE)){
        this.rowData = StringTools.makeRowData((ResultSet)e.getNewValue());
        this.columnName = StringTools.makeColumnName((ResultSet) e.getNewValue());
        repaint();

    }

}
```

and the firePropertyChangeEvent:

```
public class SuchenComboBoxControl implements ActionListener{

protected ResultSet currentRs=null;
private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);


public SuchenComboBoxControl(){

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JComboBox<?> cb = (JComboBox<?>)e.getSource();
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    switch(command){
    case SuchenCommand.TABLE:
        String tablename = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        ResultSet execRs=MysqlConnection.getResultFromStatement("select * from "+StringTools.concatForExecute(tablename));
        this.pcs.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeCommands.tableUPDATE, currentRs, execRs);
        this.currentRs=execRs;          
    }
}

public void addPropertyChangeListener (PropertyChangeListener listener){
    this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
}

public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener){
    this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
}
```

if needed you can view the whole code at [full Code](http://www.github.com/ElHeck/JavaDB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is updating the rowData and columnName variables. These variable are just sitting in memory and have nothing to do with the JTable. When you create the JTable the data from those two variables are copied to the TableModel used by the JTable.

One approach is to update the `TableModel` directly. Then the TableModel with invoke the appropriate fireXXX method to make sure the table gets updated. You can use the `setDataVector(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to reset the data in the existing TableModel. Or you can use the `setRowCount(0)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to clear the model. Then you use the `addRow(...)` method to add the new rows.

Or your other option is to create a new TableModel and add the model to the table.

```
this.rowData = StringTools.makeRowData((ResultSet)e.getNewValue());
this.columnName = StringTools.makeColumnName((ResultSet) e.getNewValue());
table.setModel( new DefaultTableModel(rowDate, columnName);
```

No need for a repaint() or anything.

Comment: ok,at first thank you that is a working solution to my problem. Is it more efficient to update the tableModel or to set a new model?

Comment: When you create a table information from the TableModel is used to create the TableColumnManager and TableColumns of the table. You may also add custom renderers and editors to the table. If you create a new TableModel (or refresh the data vector) than all this has to be done again by the table. This needs to be done if you change the structure (columns and headings), but it you are just refreshing the data then you should delete the data and add the new data back.

Comment: Ok looks like I had a wrong concept of JTable in my mind. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`fireTableDataChanged()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged()) on the `((DefaultTableModel)[JTable].getModel())`?

Comment: no, as far as i read about this, fireTableDataChanged() does exactly the same as updating my values and repainting it. Please correct me if I´m wrong. Where would you use it?

Comment: Instead of `repaint()`. After `[DefaultTableModel].setValueOf((Object)value, (int)row, (int)col))`.

Comment: It's the models responsibility to trigger the events and should NEVER be triggered externally